# AWS: error on import of OVF/OVA file from a VMWare ESXi

Tags: vmware-vmdk, ovf, aws-ec2

My goal is to migrate a VM from VMWare to AWS EC2.

I exported the "OVF+VMDK" file from VMWare ESXI 6.5.
I also converted to an OVA file to be able to test both OVF and OVA format.

I followed the tutorial provided by AWS to import a virtual machine as AMI.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html

I get an appropriate "pending" status when running the "aws ec2 import-image" command.
When I query the status later, I receive an error message:

```
"Status": "deleted",
"StatusMessage": "ClientError: Unsupported: Not enough free disk space in /boot to proceed with import.",
```

I am a bit confused about this error message. Both OVF and OVA give the same error message. Importing the same VM to virtualbox works fine.

The OVA contains a "Debian 7" machine and /boot is taking 18Megs. It is less than what I see on more recent machines with 50megs of /boot directory.

The requirements for Linux seem to be ok. My boot is a Grub.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/prepare-vm-image.html

Did anyone experiment this problem ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time investigating this.
I could solve it by freeing up some space on the VM disk (I had 20 megs available on 2Gig, I freed 200Megs). Then re-exporting it.